# Not able to identify custom checkbox element/Need relative xpath

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I need relative xpath of the span element

> ```
> <span class="icon"></span>
> ```

in selenium web driver.

```
<span class="custom-checkbox">
           <input id="personalization1" name="personalization-terms-check" class="personalization-terms-check required" value="accept" type="checkbox">
           <label for="personalization1">
               <span class="icon"></span>
               <span class="order-ready-text">yes! I double-checked all personalization entered above and i'm ready to order</span>
           </label>
</span>
```

need relative xpath of the span element

> ```
> <span class="icon">
> ```

in above html and I am getting relative path:
`//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div/span/label/span[1].`

Please help me to get an relative xpath or another way to make an click on the span

NOTE:

> ```
> <span class="icon">
> ```

It can be multiple so I need unique relative xpath.

Comment: What is the problem with what you have? *not able to click* doesn't really mean anything

Comment: I need unique relative xpath <span class="icon">

Comment: .//input[@id='personalization1'] try this

Comment: you can click the checkbox directly, why do you want to click on span element?

Comment: This is custom checkbox and i can't find checkbox by source code , i get only span element for the custom checkbox.@murthi

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath to click on checkbox:

```
.//input[@id='personalization1']
```

or you can use this xpath

```
.//span[contains(text(),'yes! I dou')]
```

Comment: have you try this?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the element visibility before performing any action like below.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='personalization-terms-check']/following-sibling::label/span"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

element.click();
```

and you can use different xpath or id to locate the element. the above xpath map be unique if only one personalization term checkbox on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this xpath?

```
"//label[@for='personalization1']/span[1]"
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Try this XPath -

`//input[@id='personalization1']/label/span`